# What regular expression will match this (XML-ish) input pattern

Tags: regex

I had a requirement that I need to parse an XML fragment which looks like this:

```
<tag name="books">books1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks2</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks3</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks4</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks5</tag> 
<tag name="books">books2</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks2</tag> 
<tag name="books">books3</tag>
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks4</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks5</tag>
```

I need to get all the tags `name="textBooks"` including `<tag name="books"></tag>` up to the last textBooks just before another `<tag name="books"></tag>`.

So the results will be as follows

```
<tag name="books">books1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks2</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks3</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks4</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks5</tag> 

<tag name="books">books2</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks1</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks2</tag> 

<tag name="books">books3</tag>
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks4</tag> 
<tag name="textBooks"> textBooks5</tag>
```

Comment: Don't use regular expression to parse XML. There are dedicated more convenient tools for this.

Comment: But my requirement is to parse this xml and get the data in it.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? What you posted may look like XML, but it isn't. If it's just a small portion of your input, and you input *is* XML, why not use an XML parser of some kind?

Comment: I am using xpath to parse the xml. But there is no start and end node for this xml to get the contents.

Comment: What do you mean by "get" the tags?  Your output looks like you added an empty line before each internal `<tag name="books">` element, but your question says nothing about modifying the input.

Comment: Regex has nothing to do with parsing XML. Every language has a tool to parse XML using dedicated library or you may use combination of XSD/XPath/XQuery yourself to parse it. Never use Regex to even test the validity of XML.

Comment: @tripleee, I just mentioned the output of the regex if you print it. Thats the expected output i am looking out.The empty space in the output is just a new line.

Comment: @HarshGupta, Thats the part of the incoming xml from server. I tried using xpath to parse the xml but unable to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is really nothing more than "which regular expression will match `<tag name="books">`" then the answer is simply `<tag name="books">`.

Your output example looks like you want to insert an empty line before each occurrence except the first, so maybe try something like

```
sed '1b;/<tag name="books">/i\
' xml-fragment.txt
```

If you mean, capture each group of `name="textBooks"` tags along with the preceding `name="books"` tag and their respective contents, try something like

```
(<tag name="books">[^<>]*(?:</tag>\s*<tag name="textBooks">[^<>]*)*</tag>)
```

where `\s` matches whitespace (including newlines) in regex implementations which include the Perl extensions (so, not `sed`, but most modern programming languages, including PHP [which I include here with a witty remark about its suitability for ... most things] and Python).

Note that many regex implementations are line-oriented by default -- applying the above multi-line regular expression to an input which is a single line will certainly not work.  But assuming you are doing something like

```
lines = file.read()
re.match(regex, lines)
:
```

you should find that it does what you want.

Like indicated in the comments, you really should use XML tools for XML input.  If your input isn't proper XML, maybe you can preprocess it so it is, and postprocess it to remove whatever the preprocessor had to add in order to make it acceptable to your XML processing pipeline.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It is working fine. But i want to understand the regex what you wrote. Can you give a brief idea of it.

Comment: Try http://regex101.com/r/eW7nY1/1